# How to create a task function with an argument using huey?

Tags: python, python-huey

[image]

I'm trying to use python huey (https://github.com/coleifer/huey/blob/master/huey/api.py) to allow usage of a task queue with flask.

Based on [TypeError: decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959304/typeerror-decorator-missing-1-required-positional-argument-func), I can use huey to create a task function without an argument using:

```
some_long_calculation_task = my_huey.task()(some_long_calculation)
```

However, I'd like to be able to pass in an argument, so I'd need something like:

```
some_long_calculation_task(arg) = my_huey.task()(some_long_calculation(arg)).
```

How would I create a task function with an argument using huey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this is the proper way to declare your task:

```
some_long_calculation_task = my_huey.task()(some_long_calculation)
```

If "some_long_calculation" accepts an argument, you can pass that argument in when you call "some_long_calculation_task":

```
# Execute the task w/the given args.
some_long_calculation_task(some_arg, another_arg)
```